# Making a standalone .exe file of a python script

Tags: python, exe, py2exe, pyinstaller

I have a python script which contains:

```
tempBook = temp.Workbooks.Open("c:\users\CNAME\desktop\Template.xlsx")
```

Everything works fine but when I create a .exe of my script the Template.xlsx is not included in its 'build' folder, it needs Template.xlsx to be present on the desktop. I want to make a portable exe.

Is there any way so that it can be included in the build, and make a standalone exe without any dependencies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move the file to your package, and list it in your `setup.py`:

```
setup(
    # ...
    data_files = [('', ['Tempate.xlsx',])],
)
```

See the [`data_files` documentation](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/data_files) for `py2exe`, which includes a utility function for automating adding data files.

The files will be added in your app root. From your main script, you can determine your app root by using:

```
import os

try:
    approot = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
except NameError:  # We are the main py2exe script, not a module
    import sys
    approot = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0]))
```