# Making a .exe file from python script. .exe does not find my modules in different folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, pyinstaller, exe

I've seen this post about a similar problem but I dont understand the solution. And I am using python 3 the other person is using python2

Link to post: [Making a standalone .exe file of a python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15634367/making-a-standalone-exe-file-of-a-python-script)

I made a python exe that uses multiple files.
When all the files are in one directory the exe works.

Now i put some order in my directory.
E.G. making a source folder where my sources are
making a script folder where my scripts are

Using an IDE the scripts still run, so the relations aren't wrong.

my directories look like this:

```
"main

main.py

sources

    sources.py
    buttons.py

scripts

    scripts.py"
```

I converted main.py to exe with pyinstaller
[image: this is the error code I get when clicking the exe]

Answer (score -1):

I made an error. Went to far up the tree to find the spoken of files.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).